# How to make speech-dispatcher work with variables?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, environment-variables, text-to-speech

I tried some bash variables with `spd-say` command just like the date variable

- `spd-say $date`

or

- `spd-say "$date"`

but didn't work with me.

So how to make it accept variables?

Comment: How you use it normally?

Comment: What do u mean normally?
[spd-say "Naruto"] is this what u r talking about?

Comment: Is there an error message?

Comment: Did you define the date variable first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you mean this:

```
spd-say "$(date)"
```

Comment: Do not thank me, give me an upvote. ;c)